# MATLABで複数の addAnalogInputChannel を同時に定義する時のエラー

Tags: c, matlab

複数の addAnalogInputChannel を同時に定義しようとしています。
MATLABドキュメントの[addAnalogInputChannel](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/addanaloginputchannel.html)に関するページを読みました。
しかし、複数のチャネルを定義するためのヒントを得ることはできす、どのように解決すればいいのか困っています。
MATLABのバージョンはR2017bです。

エラーメッセージ（実行時ではなく、プログラムを書いている時に表示されるエラー）

```
%for the line  "ch + int2str(i) ="
Parse error at '=': usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax. 
% 'Voltage');
Parse error at ')': usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax.
```

実行するスクリプト

```
num = 5
for i = 1:1:num
    ch + int2str(i) = addAnalogInputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ai' + int2str(i), 'Voltage');
end
```

下のように１つずつ書くのではなく、入力された数値に応じてチャネルを定義したいです。

```
ch1 = addAnalogInputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ai1', 'Voltage'); 
ch2 = addAnalogInputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ai2', 'Voltage'); 
ch3 = addAnalogInputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ai3', 'Voltage'); 
...to ch5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ch + int2str(i) = addAnalogInputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ai' + int2str(i), 'Voltage');
```

の部分ですが、左辺は変数`ch`の中身と`int2str(i)`の計算結果を足し合わせるという計算ですので、`ch1`のような新しい変数は作成されません。このように複数のデータを番号で区別したいときは、配列を使うのが定番のテクニックです。

`addAnlogInputChannel`は関係ないので、普通の数値を用いて説明します。

```
% 要素が5個の配列を作成 [1 4 9 16 25]
for i = 1:5
    ch(i) = i*i;
end

% 2番目を表示
disp(ch(2))

% 4番目を表示
disp(ch(4))

% 配列の要素を全て足し合わせる
s = 0;
for i = 1:5
    s = s + ch(i);
end
disp(s)
```

を実行すると

```
     4
    16
    55
```

という結果が得られます。同様に

```
num = 5
for i = 1:1:num
    ch(i) = addAnalogInputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ai' + int2str(i), 'Voltage');
end
```

として、後から`ch(1)`とか`ch(num)`などと中身を参照すればいいでしょう。

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
実装してみたところ

disp(int2str(i))で1と表示されても
disp('ai' + int2str(i)）だと「146 154」との出力で
ch(i) = addAnalogInputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ai' + int2str(i), 'Voltage');の行で以下のエラーメッセージが出力されました。

The device 'Dev!' does not have a channel 'ai146'. Valid channel IDs are 'ai0', 'ai1', 'ai2', ...

Comment: こちらの質問ではご回答をいただき、採用させていただきましたので、以下のURLで別の質問として投稿させていただきました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54960/matlab%E3%81%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%A8%E6%95%B4%E6%95%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E5%80%A4%E3%82%92%E7%B5%90%E5%90%88%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC